# Apply other physics to particles from emitter inside Blender

Tags: python, scripting, physics

I am quite new to Blender.
I would like to know how to have an `emitter` emit particles subject to a particular physics.
More precisely, I try to simulate a "parabolic" shot for which the drag coefficient is speed-dependent.
The equations of motion read

$
m_{part}
\frac{d}{dt}
\mathbf{v}
=
m
\mathbf{g}
-
\frac{1}{2}
\rho
S
C_D
\left\| \mathbf{v} \right\|
\mathbf{v},
$

where $m_{part}$ is the particle mass, $\mathbf{v}$ is the speed vector, $\rho$ is the medium density, $S$ the surface area of the particle, and $C_D$ is the drag coefficient.
That equation can be implemented in Blender by setting (please correct me if this is wrong) someting looking like

```
bpy.data.objects["Emitter_Name"].particle_systems["ParticleSystem"].settings.name = "Ball Emitter"
bpy.data.objects["Emitter_Name"].particle_systems["ParticleSystem"].parent = bpy.data.objects["Emitter_Name"]
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].type = "EMITTER"
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].lifetime = 200
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].emit_from = "FACE"
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].userjit = 1
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].physics_type = "NEWTON"
bpy.data.particles["Ball_Emitter"].integrator = "MIDPOINT"
```

but simulates a shot with constant drag. I would like to have a drag of the form

$
C_D
=
\begin{cases}
    C_{D_0}^\star \quad &\text{if } Ma < 1\\
    \frac{C_{D_0}}{Ma^k} \quad &\text{if } Ma \geq 1 \,(\text{with}\, k \in \mathbb{R}^+ ),
\end{cases}
$

where $C_{D_0}^\star$ and $C_{D_0}$ are constants, and $Ma$ is the Mach number, defined as
$
Ma
=
\frac{ \left\| \mathbf{v} \right\| }{ v_{sound} },
$
i.e. the ratio between the particle speed and the speed of sound.
So far, I have a pure python script running to compute the speed and position of a particle at each time step $\Delta t$, but I would like to be able to directly simulate such physics inside Blender.
How can I do this?